# What are the .Trash-500 and .Trash-1000 directories?

Tags: directory-structure, rm, trash

I have a DNS-321 NAS drive which apparently runs Linux, so I logged in via ssh and I see `.Trash-500` and `.Trash-1000` directories. I realize that they're for trash, but why do I need two? Inside of them I see `expunged`, `files`, and `info` directories -- what are those for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find the answers in the [The FreeDesktop.org Trash specification](http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html):

Some excerpts:

> `$topdir/.Trash-$uid` directory is to be used as the user's trash directory for this `device/partition`. `$uid` is the user's numeric identifier.
>
> The `$trash/files` directory contains the files and directories that were trashed.
>
> The `$trash/info` directory contains an “information file” for every file and directory in `$trash/files`.

There is no reference to `expunge` directory, though.

Comment: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bleachbit/+bug/388956) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/422012) are some info about `expunged`. It's apparently a temporary part of the process for emptying the trash, but stuff gets stuck if something can't be deleted.

Comment: the correct link to the spec is: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html

Comment: regarding `$trash/expunged/`, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297828/what-are-the-contents-of-contents-of-local-share-trash-expunged